# MERGE statement to update or insert rows into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

My task is to insert or update rows in a table2. Table1 contains id's of all employees. That id matches the ID in the table2. Some of the employees in table2 already have the rows I need but some don't. Table2 doesn't contain the ID's of the employees that don't have those rows.

My task is to update the rows for the existing ID's and insert for the ones that don't have those rows.

I have tried the following statement:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.table2 AS TGT
USING (SELECT table1ID FROM dbo.table1) AS SRC
      ON SRC.table1ID = TGT.table2ID

WHEN MATCHED 
     AND table2Code = 'ValueToInsertOrUpdateCode'
    THEN
       UPDATE 
       SET table2Value= 'ValueToInsertOrUpdateValue'

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN
        INSERT (table2Code, table2ID, table2Value)
        VALUES ('ValueToInsertOrUpdateCode', src.table1ID, 'ValueToInsertOrUpdateValue');
```

This currently only updates the rows that exist, but doesn't insert the rows for ID's that don't have existing rows.

Comment: You've tagged MySQL and T-SQL here, however, T-SQL is the dialect of SQL that SQL Server and SyBase uses, MySQL uses its own dialect. What product are you *actually* using here?

Comment: Edited. It's TSQL. Thanks for bringing that up @Larnu

Comment: Some [required reading](https://sqlblog.org/merge) on `MERGE`. You would likely be better off using an "Upsert", if I am honest.

Comment: Can you create a sqlfiddle with some sample data to show it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments is sounds like you want this so that the `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` is executed:

```sql
MERGE INTO dbo.table2 AS TGT
USING (SELECT table1ID FROM dbo.table1) AS SRC
      ON (SRC.table1ID = TGT.table2ID AND table2Code = 'ValueToInsertOrUpdateCode') -- This is the difference

WHEN MATCHED 
     AND table2Code = 'ValueToInsertOrUpdateCode'
    THEN
       UPDATE 
       SET table2Value= 'ValueToInsertOrUpdateValue'

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN
        INSERT (table2Code, table2ID, table2Value)
        VALUES ('ValueToInsertOrUpdateCode', src.table1ID, 'ValueToInsertOrUpdateValue');
```

`WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` would not execute when `SRC.table1ID = TGT.table2ID` (i.e. they match).

Updating the `ON` clause to `ON (SRC.table1ID = TGT.table2ID AND table2Code = 'ValueToInsertOrUpdateCode')` will give you the inserts you are expecting.

However you should probably not do this:
[ON <merge_search_condition> Caution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#on-merge_search_condition)

> It's important to specify only the columns from the target table to use for matching purposes. That is, specify columns from the target table that are compared to the corresponding column of the source table. Don't attempt to improve query performance by filtering out rows in the target table in the ON clause; for example, such as specifying AND NOT target_table.column_x = value. Doing so may return unexpected and incorrect results.

For this reason and what others have suggested it would be safer to do separate update and insert statements.

Comment: this Merge works! I will definitely take all you folks advice and try to find another way to do this and not merge. But thank you ALL for helping me figure this out. You all rock!

Answer (score 0):

I would, honestly, suggest avoiding the `MERGE` operator and doing an Upsert here instead. For your scenario, what you need is most likely the following:

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE T2 WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) 
SET table2Value = 'ValueToInsertOrUpdateValue'
FROM dbo.Table2 T2
     JOIN dbo.Table1 T1 ON T1.table1ID = T2.table2ID;
-- You could honestly use an EXISTS here, considering that you're updating the table
-- with a literal, rather than a value from the table Table1.

INSERT INTO dbo.Table2 (table2Code , table2ID, table2Value)
SELECT 'ValueToInsertOrUpdateCode',
       T1.table1ID,
       'ValueToInsertOrUpdateValue'
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.Table2 T2
                  WHERE T2.table2ID = T1.table1ID);

COMMIT;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6OKOSUol)

Comment: Thank you Larnu. I followed your example, however, in this case the function updates all rows in table2 and sets table2Value = 'ValueToInsertOrUpdateValue' and it doesn't insert the ID from table1 to table2

Comment: What "function", @brunas ?  I don't use any functions above. If, however, *every row* in `Table2` is `UPDATE`d with the above, then *every row* (in `Table2`) has a related row in `Table1`.

Comment: I've added a dbfiddle showing that what you state isn't the case, @brunas . Note that the row with `2` is `INSERT`ed, the row with `1` is `UPDATE`d and the row with `3` is left unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for the effort @larnu . However it doesn't work as intended. The first part UPDATE T2 WITH .... to the JOIN STATEMENT. This part sets the table2value for all table2Code's. The second part of the statement doesn't change any rows. I need it to only change the table2Value for the matching table2Code and if the table2Code doesn't exist for an ID, then insert that table2Code for a matching ID from table1 and set the table2Value to 'ValueToInsertOrUpdateValue'

Comment: You likely need to tweak it, @brunas , I don't have any sample data, or expected result, however, the above works *exactly* as (I) intended; it `UPDATE`s rows where the `ID`s match, and inserts new rows, where they don't. No doubt the tables you have differ in *some way* (as I doubt those are you real column and table names) so perhaps you've introduced an error? Maybe take the time to make a [mre] with it not working as you expect. I suspect the problem here if your implementation, not the solution.

Comment: I'll keep trying to. Appreciate your help @larnu.

Comment: Here is an example based on what you had described and does appear to work: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0EQgAgxc).

I think your comment "if the table2Code doesn't exist for an ID, then insert that table2Code for a matching ID from table1 and set the table2Value to 'ValueToInsertOrUpdateValue'" may be the issue. If the id's match then the merge will not go into `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN`.